# Power BI 12 months dynamic rolling total

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the total below

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE(OrderDates date,Orders decimal(9,2))
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES
('2021-01-01',160),('2021-02-01',412),('2021-03-01',101),('2021-04-01',35),('2021-05-01',497),('2021-06-01',254),
('2021-07-01',185),('2021-08-01',174),('2021-09-01',107),('2021-10-01',180),('2021-11-01',386),('2021-12-01',344),
('2022-01-01',222),('2022-02-01',18),('2022-03-01',46),('2022-04-01',313),('2022-05-01',136),('2022-06-01',457),
('2022-07-01',247),('2022-08-01',379),('2022-09-01',119),('2022-10-01',447),('2022-11-01',456),('2022-12-01',58),
('2023-01-01',346),('2023-02-01',229),('2023-01-01',18),('2023-02-01',210)
select * from @TBL
```

I want to be calculate the 12 month rolling total for each months for the last 12 months and it should update whenever there is a new month

I wrote the measure below

```
    Running 12 months Total = 
var mm = 12
var   rollingValue = CALCULATE(sum(Orders[Orders]),
  DATESINPERIOD(Orders[OrderDates] , LASTDATE(Orders[OrderDates]),-mm,MONTH))
  return
  rollingValue
```

Current Output

[image]

Desired output

[image]

[image]
My data model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it at the end

```
Running 12 months Total = 
  var   rollingValue = CALCULATE([Total],
  DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[Dates] , MAX('Calendar'[Dates]),-12,MONTH))
  return
  rollingValue
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build in **Quick measure** for **Rolling average** and in the expression replace AVERAGE() with SUM().